# How to use matlab contourf to draw two-dimensional decision boundary

Tags: matlab, contour

I finished an SVM training and got data like X, Y. X is the feature matrix only with 2 dimensions, and Y is the classification labels. Because the data is only in two dimensions, so I would like to draw a decision boundary to show the surface of support vectors.

I use contouf in Matlab to do the trick, but really find it hard to understand how to use the function.

I wrote like:

```
#1 try:    
contourf(X);

#2 try:
contourf([X(:,1) X(:,2) Y]);

#3 try:
Z(:,:,1)=X(Y==1,:);
Z(:,:,2)=X(Y==2,:);
contourf(Z);
```

all these things do not correctly. And I checked the Matlab help files, most of them make Z as a function, so I really do not know how to form the correct Z matrix.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the `svmtrain` and `svmclassify` commands from Bioinformatics Toolbox, you can just use the additional input argument `(...'showplot', true)`, and it will display a scatter plot with a decision boundary and the support vectors highlighted.

If you're using your own SVM, or a third-party tool such as libSVM, what you probably need to do is to:

1. Create a grid of points in your 2D input feature space using the `meshgrid` command
2. Classify those points using your trained SVM
3. Plot the grid of points and the classifications using `contourf`.

For example, in kind-of-MATLAB-but-pseudocode, assuming your input features are called X1 and X2:

```
numPtsInGrid = 100;
x1Range = linspace(x1lower, x1upper, numPtsInGrid);
x2Range = linspace(x2lower, x2upper, numPtsInGrid);
[X1, X2] = meshgrid(x1Range, x2Range);
Z = classifyWithMySVMSomehow([X1(:), X2(:)]);
contourf(X1(:), X2(:), Z(:))
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Actually, my problem lies in how to elegantly generate the Z. Currently I use griddata, but it is really ugly...

Answer (score 0):

I know it's been a while but I will give it a try in case someone else will come up with that issue.

Assume we have a 2D training set so as to train an SVM model, in other words the feature space is a 2D space. We know that a kernel SVM model leads to a score (or decision) function of the form:

f(x) = sum<sub>i=1 to N</sub>(*a*<sub>i</sub>*y*<sub>i</sub>k(*x*,*x*<sub>i</sub>)) + *b*

Where N is the number of support vectors, *x*<sub>i</sub> is the *i* -th support vector, *a*<sub>i</sub> is the estimated Lagrange multiplier and  *y*<sub>i</sub> the associated class label. Values(scores) of decision function in way depict the distance of the observation *x* frοm the decision boundary.

Now assume that for every point (X,Y) in the 2D feature space we can find the corresponding score of the decision function. We can plot the results in the 3D euclidean space, where X corresponds to values of first feature vector *f*<sub>1</sub>, Y to values of second feature *f*<sub>2</sub>, and Z to the the return of decision function for every point (X,Y). The intersection of this 3D figure with the Z=0 plane gives us the decision boundary into the two-dimensional feature space. In other words, imagine that the decision boundary is formed by the (X,Y) points that have scores equal to 0. Seems logical right?

Now in MATLAB you can easily do that, by first creating a grid in X,Y space:

```
d = 0.02;
[x1Grid,x2Grid] = meshgrid(minimum_X:d:maximum_X,minimum_Y:d:maximum_Y);
```

*d* is selected according to the desired resolution of the grid.

Then for a trained model *SVMModel* find the scores of every grid's point:

```
xGrid = [x1Grid(:),x2Grid(:)];
[~,scores] = predict(SVMModel,xGrid);
```

Finally plot the decision boundary

```
figure;
contour(x1Grid,x2Grid,reshape(scores(:,2),size(x1Grid)),[0 0],'k');
```

Contour gives us a 2D graph where information about the 3rd dimension is depicted as solid lines in the 2D plane. These lines implie iso-response values, in other words (X,Y) points with same Z value. In our occasion contour gives us the decision boundary.

Hope I helped to make all that more clear. You can find very useful information and examples in the following links:

[MATLAB's example](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/support-vector-machines-for-binary-classification.html#bsr5ovw-1)

[Representation of decision function in 3D space](http://mccormickml.com/2013/04/16/trivial-svm-example/)